# Query SQL column twice to build HTML table

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have two SQL tables. One table (let's call it teams) looks like:

```
team_id | team_name 
--------|-----------
    0   |    team_A
    1   |    team_B
```

And another table (called schedule) looks like:

```
game_id | home_team_id | away_team_id | date 
--------|--------------|--------------|-----------
    0   |       0      |        1     | 2013-11-05
    1   |       1      |        0     | 2013-11-07
```

How can I structure a SQL query to create a table that looks like

```
home_team | away_team | date
----------|-----------|-----------
  Team_A  |  Team_B   | 2013-11-05
  Team_B  |  Team_A   | 2013-11-07
```

I've tried using

```
SELECT schedule.date, teams.team_name AS home_team, 
       teams.team_name AS away_team 
FROM schedule 
   INNER JOIN teams ON schedule.home_team_id = teams.team_id 
   INNER JOIN schedule team ON schedule.away_team_id = teams.team_id
```

but that does not return any results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to join to teams twice, using an alias to differentiate:

```
SELECT schedule.date, ht.team_name AS home_team, 
       at.team_name AS away_team 
FROM schedule 
   INNER JOIN teams ht ON schedule.home_team_id = ht.team_id 
   INNER JOIN teams at ON schedule.away_team_id = at.team_id;
```

[Fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/347054/1)

Answer (score 0):

try the below-

```
SELECT t1.team_name AS home_team, 
             t2.team_name AS away_team,
            schedule.date
FROM schedule
   INNER JOIN teams t1 ON schedule.home_team_id = t1.team_id 
   INNER JOIN teams t2 ON schedule.away_team_id = t2.team_id
order by schedule.date
```

on executing the above u will get as

```
team_A  team_B  2013-11-05
team_B  team_A  2013-11-07
```